# ScrollMagic: combining ScrollMagic pins with "scroll easing"

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax, easing, scrollmagic

I’m trying to combine ScrollMagic pins (and other coll features) with a plain JavaScript “scroll easing” like in this site: http://www.boy-coy.com/

("Scroll easing" is achieved by placing all the content in a fixed container, and animating it’s transform-translate-y CSS. To get a scrollbar to the window, we add an absolute-positioned div in the required height.)

**How can I combine these two?**

Thanks!